# Redirecting screens based on Options selected in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in the home screen in my flutter project, an API is called to show a list of 2 options I set them as buttons.

I am trying to direct the user to a new screen once one of the options is selected with API different than if the 2nd option is selected

In the home screen `userWorkoutsAPI` shows a list with 2 Options. Option 1 has  "id": 4 and Option 2 has "id": 5

I am trying to run the `userWorkoutsAPI` based on the option selected by the user.
Here is the config.dart:

```
class Config {
  static const String apiURL = "http://00.0.0.00:0000/";
  static const String userWorkoutsAPI = "api/User/workouts/";
  static const String userWorkoutDetailsAPI = "api/User/workout_details/4/";
}
```

here is the api_service.dart:

```
  static Future<List<Exercises_Model>> fetchExercises() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userWorkoutsAPI);

    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        // HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Token $GlobalTkey',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Token xxxxxxxxxx',
      },
    );

    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body); // Decoded already
    print(responseJson);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Exercises_ModelFromJson(jsonDecode(
          response.body)); //// Decoded data is pasted to workoutsModelFromJson.
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User');
    }
  }
```

Here is the homescreen:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late Future<List<Workouts_Model>> futureWorkouts;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureWorkouts = APIService.fetchUserWorkout();
  }


                      FutureBuilder<List<Workouts_Model>>(
                        future: futureWorkouts,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<List<Workouts_Model>> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Column(
                                children: List.generate(
                                    snapshot.data!.length,
                                    (index) => GFButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        const Exercises()));
                                          },
                                          text: snapshot.data![index].name,
                                          blockButton: true,
                                        )));
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) ;
                          print(snapshot.error);

                          {
                            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                          }
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        },
                      ),
```

How can I direct the user to `exercises.dart` after selecting a specific option and adding the correct ID in the api url to get the data and display it in `exercises.dart`

Answer (score 0):

use `if else statement`
i.e

```
if(snapshot.data![index].id==1){
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) =>const Exercises()));
}else if(snapshot.data![index].id==2){
//other option
}
else{
//default option
}
```

the challenge is if you have a long list will be a long code: so maybe you introduce another parameter field that groups the data

Comment: Thanks.. that is exactly what I am trying to figure there could be multiple options with different ids but how can I put it as parameter to add the id into the url of the api

Comment: How many Screens do you have..if they similar abit maybe you have one screen where you pass the model data but the widgets you display depends on that id